# Lumen $request->input() return null in middleware

Tags: php, lumen

I'm building a RESTful server within Lumen, but `$request->input("something")` and even `$request->all()` always return empty array or null, when I am passing query parameters to it. So, the question is - what am I doing wrong, and how to get parameters via $request->input () or $request->all ()?

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$router->group(['prefix' => 'accounts/{old}'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('register', function ($old)    {
        return 'You are OK! More than 18! '.$old.' years';
    });
});
```

**app/Http/Middleware/OldMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OldMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Check user old and if it was less than 18 return something and else continue.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('old') < 18) { 
            return "You are under 18!";
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**bootstap/app.php**

```
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware::class
]);
```

**Request example:**

```
curl http://server.loc/accounts/20/register
```

In OldMiddleware.php, The $request->input() return null and I can't access to old passed value in middleware (to validate the age of user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This way looks crazy!

```
$request->route('old');
```

Don't forget to import Requests (in 2nd line, after php start tag):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```